# Is it possible to ignore runtime imports in Java classpath JARs on compilation?

Tags: java, ant, dependencies, javac

I'm attempting to compile a large Java project using javac via Ant. This is on a Mac with the Yosemite OS, using Java 8, if that's relevant.

Without getting into specifics, my Class A has a dependency on Class B, which is included in a third-party library. The third-party JAR library **is** on the classpath. I don't own the source code for it. Class B apparently has a dependency on Class C, which **will** be present at runtime on the application server's classpath, but is not present during build.

The compilation fails saying that it can't find Class C. If I include the server JAR containing Class C on my classpath, the build works fine. However, *other developers can build the project without including the server JAR on the classpath*, and I'd rather not include server JARs in my build if I can avoid it.

Analogous Ant output below:

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 180 source files to /some/directory/output
    [javac] /some/directory/src/A.java:123: error: cannot access C
    [javac]  return B.build();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   class file for C not found
    [javac] 1 error
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to always convince Java to ignore this type of runtime dependency? It's working for other developers, who are mostly using Java 7.
2. Why does this not happen for every runtime dependency? I've seen this happen in the past during various projects, but it's never consistently a problem.

Comment: So is there seriously nothing that does this? I'm thinking about modifying `javac` so there's a "SHUT UP AND BUILD" flag. I probably spend more time trying to make the compiler happy than I spend actually writing/fixing code when I'm working with Java. I like type checking in theory, but in practice, I think it's faster to figure out a runtime exception than to resolve compile time dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will absolutely try to find the classes that you reference "normally": (ie. directly with the class name symbol, just "referenced" henceforth) at compile time, to catch all kinds of things that could go wrong later, and warn you about them and/or make you fix them before compiling.

You have only a couple of options.

1) Include the dependencies on your classpath while building, so the compiler can find them.   This is the normal, sane way to go about this.  Why don't you want to do it this way?

2) Access and load the classes in question with reflection, so that they explicitly resolve and verify at runtime, rather than classload time. This is normally not a great way to go about things.

3) (best imho) Migrate your project to a build system like Maven, which has dependency tracking and takes care of all these details of "what should the classpath be while I build", etc.   You could use the "provided" dependency scope to indicate to Maven that your actual implementation of the classes you reference in a particular dependency is not in your application, but will be provided later...  (Ivy is also good and both build work on top of Ant)

If other developers are compiling code that references class `C`, I assure you they have a C.class somewhere on their classpath.

Comment: The question isn't about code that references C. The class that references C is B, which is already compiled and is available to me only in binary .class form. None of our code explicitly references C. I reference binary class B that itself references C. (And I'm actually asking this on behalf of another developer - I'm the other developer who can build this without C. Works fine in Java 7.)

Comment: I bet you have a C.class in your classpath, then. =p

Comment: Source vs. compiled classes is irrelevant - the compiler doesn't need source for referenced classes, just the classfile (it will recursively compile a classfile if it is not there and there is source, however).   If C is exported through B (perhaps it uses a C as a method parameter, return value, or non-private field), the compiler will still want to poke at C and have a look.

Comment: Late returning to the party, but the other developer did install Java 7 and the build proceeded normally. This is definitely a Java version issue, but I don't have time to try to reproduce it. It's possible that Java 8 digs a bit deeper into classpath entries during compilation.

Comment: this is absolutely bad answer. Maybe I want to compile class to introspect it and then do something and it is easier than to write parser to parse java source code and my code has no access to the whole source you need to compile normally

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say here, @Enerccio.   As I said in a comment above (nine years ago!), the compiler doesn't care if it has a classfile, or source that it can compile into a classfile, at compile-time.   No one is suggesting anywhere that you "write [a] parser to parse java source code".   Please read the answer again.